# R: Highlight points in boxplot with groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to highlight some points in a boxplot with groups. I have a dataset with 4 possible diagnostics, among which diagnostic 1 correspond to AN points and diagnostic 2 to CRC points.

It works fine for boxplot without groups. I plot only AN points first (with ggforce::geom_sina), then I add CRC points with geom_point :

```
# data generation
company_a <- sample(1:200, 100,replace = TRUE)
company_b <- sample(1:200, 100,replace = TRUE)
company_c <- sample(1:200, 100,replace = TRUE)
diagnostic<- sample(1:4, 100,replace = TRUE)
diagnostic<-as.factor(diagnostic)

df<-data.frame(company_a,company_b,company_c,diagnostic)
df_r=gather(df, "Companies", "FIT", 1:3)    


# extract subdataset
CRC_df = df_r[df_r$diagnostic==2,]
AN_df = df_r[df_r$diagnostic==1,]

# Changing diagnostic ID of CRC points to identify them as AN points
df_r["diagnostic"][df_r["diagnostic"] == 2]<-1
CRC_df["diagnostic"][CRC_df["diagnostic"] == 2]<-1

# Creating boxplot
cl <- qualitative_hcl(5, palette = "Dark 3")
ggboxplot(AN_df, x = "Companies", y = "FIT",
          fill = "Companies", palette = cl,alpha=0.1)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 200, 25))+
  ggforce::geom_sina(aes(x=Companies, y=FIT, color=Companies), size=1, alpha=0.8)+
  geom_point(                               # add the highlight points
    data=CRC_df, 
    aes(x=Companies, y=FIT,color=Companies),
    size=3)
```

producing this kind of graph where the highlighted points are on their corresponding boxplot:
[image: producing this kind of graph where the highlighted points are on their corresponding boxplot]

But if I try to plot all the points in df_r and group boxplot by diagnostic ID:

```
ggboxplot(df_r, x = "diagnostic", y = "FIT",
          fill = "Companies", palette = cl,alpha=0.1)+  
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 200, 25))+
  ggforce::geom_sina(aes(x=diagnostic, y=FIT, color=Companies), size=1, alpha=0.8)+
  geom_point(                               # add the highlight points
    data=CRC_df, 
    aes(x=diagnostic, y=FIT,color=Companies),
    size=3)
```

So, it does not work as I expected as the points are not anymore on their corresponding boxplot. They collapse all on the middle boxplot corresponding to the AN group:
[image: it does not work as I expected as the points are not anymore on their corresponding boxplot]

I would like the CRC points corresponding to company_a to be on the first boxplot of AN group, and same for other company.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rosalie and welcome to SO.

The main problem I see is that you have to define your `diagnostic` variable as a factor. Otherwise, R is using it as a normal number and cannot group it accordingly.

First, is a solution using only the base `ggplot2` functions including the function `geom_jitter()` replacing `geom_sina()` from the `ggforce` package:

```r
library(tidyverse)

#data generation
company_a <- sample(1:200, 100,replace = TRUE)
company_b <- sample(1:200, 100,replace = TRUE)
company_c <- sample(1:200, 100,replace = TRUE)
diagnostic<- sample(1:4, 100,replace = TRUE)

df<-data.frame(company_a,company_b,company_c,diagnostic)
df_r=gather(df, "Companies", "FIT", 1:3)

df_r$diagnostic <- as.factor(df_r$diagnostic)

#Creating boxplot
df_r %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = diagnostic, y = FIT, fill = Companies))+
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.1, position = "dodge2")+
  geom_point(aes(color = Companies), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))+
  geom_jitter(aes(color = Companies), position = position_dodge2(width = 0.75), size = 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 200, 25))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

Second there is another solution also using the `geom_sina()` function:

```r
#Creating boxplot
df_r %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = diagnostic, y = FIT, fill = Companies))+
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.1, position = "dodge2")+
  geom_point(aes(color = Companies), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))+
  ggforce::geom_sina(aes(color = Companies), size = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 200, 25))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Indeed I forgot to convert the diagnostic as a factor variable, but it was done in my real code. The point is that I do not want to highlight all the points. I was not very clear in my post, I will edit. The change in diagnostic ID is important. I want the CRC points to be highlighted among the AN points. So in the last images, the highlighted points should be only on the first 3 boxplots and should correspond only to CRC points.